# Selenium with python bindings launches Firefox but not Explorer and Chrome browsers

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to launch Internet Explorer (8) browser on Windows XP SP3 using selenium. I coded these lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
class InternetExplorer8:
    def ie8(self):
        self.browser=webdriver.Ie()
        self.browser.get("http://www.begueradj.com")
if __name__=='__main__':
    IE=InternetExplorer8()
    IE.ie8()
```

I got this error:

> self.iedriver.start() File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\service.py", line
>   73, in start and read up at
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver")
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'IEDriver
>   executable needs to be available in the path. Please download from
>   http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up
>   at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Note that I launch firefox without any problem using the same code, except internet explorer and crhome (that outputs a similar error). How could I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [download Internet Explorer driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list?can=1&q=IE&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) and place the path to it into `PATH` environment variable.

Or, alternatively, provide an `executable_path` argument to `webdriver.Ie()`:

```
self.browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='path\to\iedriver\driver.exe')
```

Comment: May I disturb you by one additional question, Alexander ? I wonder why for Firefox browser I did not need to install a specific driver to launch it with selenium while I need so for IE ?

Comment: @begueradj yeah, this is how it works for any webdriver except Firefox.

Comment: Howdy Alexander, do you have time to answer me this question please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887599/how-to-get-image-uri-in-selenium